# Can i use Entity Framework 6.4 in .Net Standard Library (not .Net Framewrok Library)? If yes, How?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am able to use .Net Framework Library with ASP.Net Core 2.2 and Entity Framework 6.4 but I want to use .Net Standard library with EF 6.4 instead of .Net Framework Library.

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and i am able to compile asp.net core 2.2 Web app and EF 6.4 .Net Framework class library.  My question is how can i use .Net Standard library 2.1 instead of .Net framework library.

Comment: "unable to compile" is not helpful. What error do you get? Please give information that allows people to help you.

Comment: Getting below Error while running "Enable-Migrations" command in Package manager console:
"Project Targets Framework '.Net Standard'. The Entity Framework package Manager Console Tools don't support this framework."

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to resolve the problem by putting below lines in .net standard's .csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
<PropertyGroup/>
```